# On click event update template

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I´m working on a meteor example. I get the value of one tag on click event on the link. That value is the same that is present on one collection inside doc "pet" or "zoo". I want to use this value to filter the content present on the template.

A minimal example:

```
    {{#each Animal}}
        <div>
          <span> {{pet}} </span> 
        </div>
        <div>
          <span> {{zoo}} </span> 
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

After click:

```
{{#each Animal}}
        <div>
          <span> {{zoo}} </span> 
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

On this case when I get the value present in "zoo" I just want to update the template with all the the spans that contains elements on doc zoo, and that all related to pet dissappear.

The query to mongodb is working perfectly, my problem is that I´m a little bit confused.

Should I use helpers?

**Thank you so much.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I understood correctly your problem.

You should use a Session variable where you store the action you are doing. Then add a template `if` and print inside of this tag whatever you want to show at that time.

Let's do a minimal example:

```
<template name="showAnimalsTemplate">
   {{if showAnimals}}
   {{#each Animal}}
      <div>
        <span> {{pet}} </span> 
      </div>
      <div>
        <span> {{zoo}} </span> 
      </div>
   {{/each}}
   {{/if}}
   {{if showZoo}}
   {{#each Animal}}
      <div>
        <span> {{zoo}} </span> 
      </div>
   {{/each}}
   {{/if}}
```

Following this example, you add in the client javascript something like this:

```
 Template.showAnimalsTemplate.showAnimals = function(){
     if( Session.get('action') == 'showingTheZoo')
           return true;
     return false;
 }

 Template.showAnimalsTemplate.showZoo = function(){
     if( Session.get('action') == 'showingTheZoo')
           return true;
     return false;
 }
```

Don't forget to set the session value inside the click event.

```
Session.set('action', 'showingTheZoo');
```